# What is lost from the stack when a service handles async messages in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I'm using the messaging feature of ServiceStack for back end transactions I expect to involve database locks where consistency is very important.

I've registered handlers as explained in the documentation:

```
mqHost.RegisterHandler<Hello>(m => {
    return this.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m);
});
```

I've noticed the Filters don't get called. Presumably, they're really "Http" filters similar to MVC. So it makes sense they're ignored.

How does Authorization work with message handlers, is it ignored too?

And as I want to keep my async services internal, and always async, is there any benefit in making them inherit from ServiceBase at all?

As I'm thinking of creating another envelop layer between IMessage and Body for some Identity data that can be passed from my public services out of AuthSession and to the Async service.

Comment: I guess much of this has been covered here. I'd be more likely to come across it if this was added to the Wiki.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839971/how-to-set-up-handlers-in-redmq-from-events-raised-in-my-domain